# Timestamp of 'responseReceived()' in Selenium DevTools

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, selenium-grid

While using Selenuim i want to analyse all responses. Therefor i am using the chrome devTools.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.v109.network.*;
```

I am using this Listener setup:

```
devTools.addListener(Network.responseReceived(), response -> {
                    if (response.getType().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("xhr")) {
...
}}
```

for requests i can use `request.getWallTime()` to extract the timestamp

but for responses i do not have that getter.
However `response.getResponse().getResponseTime()` is available..

How can i extract the exact timestamp of when the *response* was received?

Thank you..

Comment: Suggest you use native VBA, capture value for `Now()` at then start of your process, and then capture `Timer` at each interval of interest.  `Timer` returns ms from midnight(1000 equals 1 second).

Comment: yes, that was a possible solution